# asp.net mvc bundle expires headers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I recently changed from squishit.framework to the built in bundling with asp.net mvc and am seeing the expires headers of the bundles (js and css) is set to expire immediately.

How to set the expires headers for these? I thought they were meant to be set for 1 year automatically?

Thanks

EDIT: Exipres headers are being set correctly, my fault. The problem is that when I refresh the page I get status 200 everytime. This should be 304. Only when I do a hard refresh the content should be loaded again.

If I compare this with squishit.framework, there is a file added to the file system from where I can manually set the expires headers in IIS. After refreshing that, I do get a http 304 not modified until I do a hard refresh (ctrl+F5)

Comment: Are you looking at a debug build?  Try looking at it in release.

Comment: I set the compilation debug="false", if it were set to true it wouldn't be combining files.

Comment: You are confusing a debug build (ie, compiling with the DEBUG symbol defined) with enabling debug information.  You need to build your project in release mode, as well as setting the web.config flag as well.

Comment: No this is a release build. But thanks for pointing out, I didn't know that would make a difference.

Comment: Are you looking in Chrome with dev-tools on? Is "disable cache" option clicked?

Comment: No, when I switch back to squishit(see edit) I do get a 304.